# Sync data on two DB's

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, quickbase

This is just a conceptual question. If we are trying to update our records on two servers. One locally and second on some remote server (like parse or QB). What is the best way to save it.

1) Should we save it remotely first and then on local machine

2) Save it locally and then save it to remote.

I'm currently sticking to 1st point as it will only create record locally if it can be saved on remote.

Have you're say.

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same  in my company. What we did we used the live server from which the process was being done and update the records on local server in sync. The problem was identified as database transfer in few complexities if stopped then sync or update stops. Now if the process stops on live/remote server it will be affecting the client process. On local server post the remote server we could be able to resolve any issue not affecting the other important one.